# React Native check if app notification enabled on Android

Tags: android, react-native, android-notifications

User is able to turn off app notification on Android. Is there a way to check if the user did so?

The [React Native doc](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/permissionsandroid.html) did not mention Notification permission as it's not a permission that requires prompting the user.

[Android docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#ACCESS_NOTIFICATION_POLICY) did mention the ability to access notification policy.

Comment: If you can do it in android, you can do it in RN.  Just write a native module that calls the proper API

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found one library called [React-native-permission-settings](https://github.com/alienslab02/react-native-permission-settings)

It is available for **android** only so if you need iOS support also i think you need to modify it.

You can follow installation guide from [here](https://github.com/alienslab02/react-native-permission-settings#installation)

And implement it in your code

```
import NotificationSettings from 'react-native-permission-settings';

...

NotificationSettings.areNotificationsEnabled((isEnabled: boolean) => {
  console.log(`Notifications are enabled: ${isEnabled}`);
});
```

Comment: This library no longer works as of RN 0.55 and Android 8.0. Any other recommendations?

Answer (score 2):

I have used this one in previous experiences with good results:

https://github.com/jigaryadav/react-native-check-notification-enable

Basically what I ended up implementing as helpers were this two functions:

```
export const getNotificationStatus = async () => {
  if (Platform.OS === 'ios') {
    const status = await Permissions.check(PermissionRequested.NOTIFICATION)
    if (status === PermissionsStatus.AUTHORIZED) {
      return true
    } else {
      return false
    }
  } else {
    // This is where I am using the library
    const status = await NotificationManager.areNotificationsEnabled()
    return status
  }
}

export const openNotificationsSettings = () => {
  if (Platform.OS === 'ios') {
    Linking.openURL('app-settings:')
  } else {
    AndroidOpenSettings.appNotificationSettings()
  }
}
```

Just to explain a bit the whole snippet:

I am also using these libraries in conjunction to achieve all: Check if they are enabled and navigate to the settings page to revoke if needed

```
import AndroidOpenSettings from 'react-native-android-open-settings'
import NotificationManager from 'react-native-check-notification-enable'
import Permissions from 'react-native-permissions'
```